# Combine two SELECT queries IF one is not found

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, where-clause

I'm looking to combine two select queries into one query efficiently with performance in mind.

I want the first `SELECT` to get a row. If the row does **not** exist, then run the other `SELECT` query. If the row does exist from the first query, then use the row found in the first query and do not run/get anything from the second query.

Here are my two queries:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE unique_code = :unique_code LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(':unique_code', $uniqueCode);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if(!$row) { // If row does not exist
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE birthday = :birthday LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindParam(':birthday', $birthday);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
}
```

How can I do that?

EDIT: sample data:

```
id | unique_code | birthday
-----------------------------
 1       123      1987-05-20
 2       456      1955-03-10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one query by combining your `WHERE` conditions and then ordering dependent on which one matched:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE unique_code = :unique_code OR birthday = :birthday
ORDER BY unique_code = :unique_code DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If the unique code matched, `unique_code = :unique_code` will be 1 and since we are sorting DESCENDING, that row will come first (and be the only row remaining after the `LIMIT` clause. If the unique code doesn't match, then if there are any rows they must a match on the birthday.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nEBt37UBnAqNH5YRJmM2C9/0)

Comment: Great answer! But here is the problem. When I add more `AND` conditions after birthday, it doesn't work. Here is how it's supposed to be: `WHERE unique_code = :unique_code OR (birthday = :birthday AND name = :name AND gender = :gender)` and everything else is the same. It does not work

Comment: It doesn't pull the row. With your code, I was able to get the row. Then I changed the `birthday` condition to `(birthday = :birthday AND name = :name AND gender = :gender)` and it's supposed to pull the same row but it doesn't. Actually, it doesnt have to do with the `name` or `gender` data as it should get the row using the first condition

Comment: @baileyJchoi are you binding values for the other parameters?

Comment: Yes I am binding them

Comment: Here is my full code: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE unique_code = :unique_code OR (birthday = :birthday AND name = :name AND gender = :gender) ORDER BY unique_code = :unique_code DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Where is the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Sorry edited my previous comment. In the code, it has the `ORDER BY` clause but it still does not work

Comment: @baileyJchoi Can you put some sample data into the question? I don't see why that shouldn't work

Comment: Yes, just added some two rows of sample data in the OP. So unique_code should equal `123`. When you try to get the row, it returns null

Comment: @baileyJchoi I added a demo link which shows the query working as expected. Can you try and edit that to show it not working?

Comment: Hmm that’s very weird. It’s working on the demo link. I will have to figure it out tomorrow, it’s getting late here. I appreciate your help and not leaving me hanging. :)